# Please advise. How can I export all product images at once Magento 2.2.5?

Tags: magento2, product, image, export

I am having an product export issue with **Magento 2.2.5**. How can I download/export all of my product images (all at once)? They all are in different folders on server? Thanks!

Comment: Do you only want the images or you want them against sku?

Answer (score 0):

**Magento import export** functionality simply exports all the content available into the database related to the products. You can definitely have the images name with their directory location(following the below directory structure) present at below location.

> Magento_root/pub/media/catalog/product/

But if you are talking about the physical images should get downloaded with the one click export it is not feasible with Magento export functionality if you really want to download them then you can get them in single file by simply compressing the *product* directory or content of *product* directory available at below location

> Magento_root/pub/media/catalog/product/

Then export the **`product_data.csv`** file to **map them** with their further directory structure with their appropriate names.